# Is it better to use the same loop in different functions or different functions in one loop?

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I have a class that contains different member variables, one of which is a list of dictionaries. I have to perform some operations on that list such as:

- finding and replacing some elements
- adding a new key value to some dictionaries in that list
- removing some empty key values from some dictionaries in that list
- etc.

I initially did different functions where each function performs a certain task on the list of dictionaries (`Option1`). I then realized that in each of these functions I am doing the same looping over the same list. I thought it would be more performant if I looped once over the loop and did all the tasks I needed to do in there. So, I created different functions that do the operations that I want to do on the element level instead of the list level as shown in `Option2`.

Calling a function also takes a certain overhead, so my question would be:  is it better from a performance perspective to go with `Option1` or `Option2`? Which option would the compiler better optimize? What about from a code maintainability and readability perspective?

**Option1**

```
def add_status(self):
    for element_dict in self.list_of_dicts:
        element_dict["status"] = function_to_add_status()

def replace_id_with_name(self):
    for element_dict in self.list_of_dicts:
        element_dict["name"] = function_to_get_name()
        element_dict.pop("id")

def remove_empty_elements(self):
    for k, v in list(element_dict.items()):
        if v == "null":
            del element_dict[k]

def clean_up(self):
    self.add_status()
    self.replace_id_with_name()
    self.remove_empty_elements()
```

**Option2**

```
def add_status(element_from_list_of_dicts):
    element_from_list_of_dicts["status"] = function_to_add_status()

def replace_id_with_name(element_from_list_of_dicts):
    element_from_list_of_dicts["name"] = function_to_get_name()
    element_dict.pop("id")

def remove_empty_elements(element_from_list_of_dicts):      
    if element_from_list_of_dicts.item() == "null":
        del element_from_list_of_dicts[k]

def clean_up(self):
    for element_dict in self.list_of_dicts:
        self.add_status(element_dict)
        self.replace_id_with_name(element_dict)
        self.remove_empty_elements(element_dict)
```

Comment: ... Have you tried doing any profiling? The best way to know which option is more performant is to *look and see for yourself*.

Comment: Time it yourself. But as a rule of thumb, the overhead of calling a function is a very minor thing compared to having to iterate twice more in a list.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga .. profiling was next on my to do list. @paritosh-singh .. I did some test runs with some dummy data and measured the execution time of both implementations: `Option1` was 5% faster than `Option2`. I am not sure though if this would still hold when the list grows to a much higher order of magnitude. As you mentioned, calling a function is a small overhead compared to iterating multiple times in a huge list.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Even if there's a difference, it will usually be negligible, so only worry about this when you actually have a performance problem.

Comment: The important thing to know here is why you have these functions in the first place.  That governs what interface you should have; the optimal *implementation* might involve ugly things like duplicated code that you might choose to generate dynamically.